# Почему нечто бывает "забористым"?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Например, о крепком спиртном напитке говорят, что он "забористый". Интересно, при чем тут забор?)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Забористым бывает не только спиртной напиток, но и лук,  горчица, табак и т.п. У глагола забирать есть значение(разговорное)-  давать себя чувствовать, оказывать сильное действие (У Кузнецова, например). Отсюда и забористый -  сильнодействующий, едкий, крепкий.

А забор (ограда) от другого значения глагола забирать - заделывать, загораживать.

Comment: >от другого значения глагола забирать - заделывать, загораживать.   
   
Почему так сложно? Разве забор землю не "забирает" в прямом значении?

С остальным согласен.

Comment: Видел когда-то в поликлинике табличку **"Забор крови"**. Там, где кровь **берут** на анализы.

:-) Я тогда был маленький. И мне всё какой-то дощатый забор представлялся, такой, с заострёнными сверху досками. Вот сейчас вспомнилось.

Так что была и у меня накладка с этими значениями :-)

Comment: > заострёнными сверху досками. 
Ага, красными, от крови предыдущих жертв. 

Ну да, в сознании современных носителей пропала связь забора и забирать. А ведь она очевидно была.

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно. 
Забористый - от "забирать", "охватывать", "присваивать". В прямом значении - землю, огораживаемую забором, в переносном - человека, тем или иным образом: про чувства, эмоции, ну или физиологически, если это про спиртное, табак или наркотик.